# How to seed entity framework core data with related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have these two classes:

```
public class Item
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Store Location { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to seed some example data in my ASP.NET Core Entity Framework Core WebAPI Code First application.

So I saw I can use something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasData(new Item {<properties>});
```

Two problems:

1. If I don't provide a value for "ID" I get an exception that it is required.
2. If I provide a value for Location like `new Store{<etc.>}` I get an error that no value was provided for `LocationID` which is the column in my database in table "Items" that is a foreign key linking that table with table "Stores".

How do I seed a new "Item" in my database when that class doesn't have a "LocationID" property? And must I first specifically add a "Store" before adding an "Item"? I was hoping there would be some sort of automatic cascade insert.

Comment: I would look into how you seed a db with EF Core.  I used to do it a lot with EF.  This has nothing to do with API

Comment: All you are asking is explained in [Model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) and [Limitations of model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data) sections of the [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your questions:

1. You just provide Id since you are seeding initial data
2. You have to insert Stores, there is no such thing as "cascade insert", what would EF insert as Name in automatically generated Stores?

So you need also to seed your Stores like you are seeding Items:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Store>().HasData(new Store {<properties>});
```

What would I also do, is to change you models like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StoreId { get; set; } //or LocationId  if you prefer

    [Required]
    public Store Location { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and you need to set this as foreign key for your Location object:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOne(e => e.Location)
                .WithMany(e => e.Items)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.StoreId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

after that you can just adjust your seed method to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasData(new Item { Id = 1, StoreId = 1 });
```

Note that there is no need to instantiate Location object.

Comment: `new Item { Location = new Store { Name = "aaa" } }` ? idk, i'm just spitballing ideas and am, obviously, not bright enough to come up with a good answer.

Comment: Oh, my! Yes, I did. Sorry! I thought I had accepted your answer.